# How to find which row/cell at center of the Screen in UITableView?

Tags: ios, uitableview

i have UITableview , many rows/cell in tableview.

when UITableview scrolling at that time , find which row/cell at center of the Screen.

Comment: show us your source code that has issues

Answer (score 7):

In Swift 4

For exact index number at center we can simply use:-

```
let middleIndex = ((heightTableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows?.first?.row)! + (heightTableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows?.last?.row)!)/2
```

Answer (score 6):

There are a couple of options for getting the central row. One would be to get the indexPath at the centre:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPathAtCenter = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:CGPointMake(self.tableView.bounds.size.width/2, self.tableView.bounds.size.height/2)];
UITableViewCell *centerCell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPathAtCenter];
```

Alternatively you could get all visible indexPaths and choose the middle one:

```
NSArray<NSIndexPath*> *visibleIndexPaths = [self.tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows];
NSIndexPath *middleIndexPath = visibleIndexPaths[visibleIndexPaths.count/2];
UITableViewCell *centerCell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: middleIndexPath];
```

Depends on the rest of your implementation which route you want to go!

Answer (score 5):

A more elegant solution based on previous answers, for Swift 4 & 5:

```
let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: tableView.bounds.center)
```

Using this little `CGRect` extension:

```
extension CGRect {
    var center: CGPoint {
        return CGPoint(x: self.midX, y: self.midY)
    }
}
```